# COM port quits working

Tags: winapi, serial-port, port

Environment: WinXP; PowerBuilder 11.5 (though probably not relevant because this portion is almost entirely WinAPI calls)

My application opens a COM port for writing using overlapped method calls. The port is opened when the application is opened. The app leaves the port open at all times.

Occasionally, the attached device stops receiving data even though the app is still sending data. The app receives no error messages. Stopping and restarting the app doesn't fix it. Rebooting the computer doesn't fix it. However, connecting via hyperterminal fixes it.

This particular device prints barcode labels. The app will be printing just fine, then suddenly, it won't print. Close the app; open and connect with hyperterminal; disconnect and close hyperterminal; open the app. It works just fine again... for a while. (I've had similar issues with other devices that also communicate via COM port, so I know it's not the device itself.)

The closest similar issue I can find on the web is at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/microsoft/Windows-XP-Hardware/30829577/com1-not-behaving.aspx which speaks of IRQ conflicts and offers no solution. I can only guess that my problem is similar.

Does anyone know what hyperterminal might be doing to clear things up?

Comment: The strong indicator is that you're getting the handshake wrong.  Like using none when the device requires RTS+CTS or Xon/Xoff.

Comment: That's certainly a possibility. But would something like that work some of the time? The app works for a while then suddenly stops. Also, how would I specify the handshake method when using the CreateFile method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You specify it in the DCB with SetCommState()

Comment: Hans Passant, can you please post that as an answer so I can mark it accepted? It would appear that specifying the handshake has resolved the issue.

Comment: Please post and accept your own answer.  Do mention what DCB setting you changed.

Answer (score 0):

I've explicitly set the handshake method using SetCommState and that appears to have resolved the issue. PowerBuilder doesn't have bit operands, so I had to create a method that turned a DWORD number into a character array of '1's and '0's. I created a corresponding method that turned the character array back into a DWORD. So, I grabbed the current state using GetCommState, translated the flags into an array, walked the array copying the existing values except for the ones that specify flow control (DTR Control and RTS Control-- not sure if I needed both) which I explicitely set to '0', then translated the resulting array back to a DWORD and used SetCommState to apply it.

For those researching, please remember that DTR Control and RTS Control are both two bits each. Decimal values for these are:

```
CONSTANT ULong fDtrControl_Enable = 2^4
CONSTANT ULong fDtrControl_Handshake = 2^5
CONSTANT ULong fRtsControl_Enable = 2^12
CONSTANT ULong fRtsControl_Handshake = 2^13
CONSTANT ULong fRtsControl_Toggle = fRtsControl_Enable + fRtsControl_Handshake
```

Comment: Well, sad face, it turns out that this DIDN'T fix it. It's a sporadic issue and the customer apparently just had a lucky streak of several days without it popping up. Either it's not a handshake issue or I'm not setting the handshake settings right. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is very late, but I've experienced similar problems on multiple devices, primarily on USB devices that have a USB/COM port driver.

The symptom that I have found is the COM port sporadically closes all on its own.  I've traced this problem to two potential issues:

1. The USB/COM driver can have bugs that cause the port to close.  Try an updated driver.
2. Electrical noise on the USB wire coming into the computer can cause the port to close. If you experience this problem, you may not be able to solve the problem easily.

   Try to isolate the electrical environment so noise doesn't enter via the USB wire.

   If you can't, you may have to modify your application to detect a closed port, and then perform a driver reset, which is the same thing as unplugging and re-plugging the USB cable, then pause a little to make sure the reset actually takes.